# Change font and colors in Visual Studio's SSIS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, colors, ssis, ssis-2012

Please see below image, I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I cant see when a data flow is enabled or disabled.

In the below image only the first Data Flow is actually enabled!! Hard to see it hey!
[image]

Would like to know where exactly I can change the font in one of these components when I disable them in my flow.

Image location: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gQ2n.png

Answer (score 0):

To change these settings choose Tools from the Menu Bar then click Options

Once options opens up select "Fonts and Colors". 
In the Drop Down for "Show Settings for:" select the option "Business Intelligence Designers"
Once selected you will be able to specify the Font, Size, Item Foreground Color...etc.

That should give you what you're needing.

Comment: Nope.. For me, that changed item description fonts and sizes ( for example the headers on steps/tasks)... My annotation color is still light grey and can BARELY be seen.

Comment: Sure enough! It looks like everything works for both the Business Intelligence Designers and Annotations except changing the font color. I'm able to change the font, fontsize and typeface (bold, regular etc) but the color doesn't change. I set my color theme to dark to see if that made a difference. I wonder if this was a byproduct of the newer two toned color scheme for VS2012? Seems like you should still be able to specify the color of the text if you want to do that though. Maybe a good thing to submit to the Microsoft Connect Site: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer

Comment: Thanks! At least you confirmed that I'm not seeing things.